# Java Swing ComponentResized doesn't fire if an invoked process is running

Tags: java, swing, processbuilder

I have a Java Swing graphics app which can run a compiled program using ProcessBuilder.  The strange thing (to me anyway) is that, when the compiled program is running, ComponentResized events aren't recognized - instead they seem to be stored until the compiled program terminates. Is there a way to run the compiled program at a lower priority than my graphics program? TIA

Schematically:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList); 
try { 
    Process proc = pb.start(); 
} catch (IOException e) {}
if (proc != null) { 
    try { 
        proc.waitFor(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block e1.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    proc.destroy();
}
```

Should this run under a separate thread or SwingWorker?

Comment: That sounds like you are blocking the EDT (the event dispatch thread) that dispatches all incoming events. Can you show how you are running the compiled program?

Comment: *Is there a way to run the compiled program...* - as suggested above your code is running on the EDT so the GUI can't respond to events until the long running code finishes executing. The solution is to have the long running code execute in a separate Thread. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT and the SwingWorker.

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen! Schematically: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
   try {
    Process proc = pb.start();

   }
   if (proc != null) {
    try {
     proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    proc.destroy();`   Should this run under a separate Thread or SwingWorker?

Comment: Yes, you should run this code in a separate Thread or SwingWorker, because `proc.waitFor();` blocks the current thread until the process terminates.

Comment: The SwingWorker IS the Thread. It has methods that allow you to update the GUI when the background task is finished. People generally use the SwingWorker so they don't have to replicate this functionality in a custom Thread. Read the tutorial and test the examples.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas and @camickr !   It is working fine in a separate thread.  Earlier today I thought I had to signal to the graphics app that the invoked process had terminated, but then I realized that the user will see that the process has terminated and then can continue working with the graphics app.   I will take a look at SwingWorker - maybe it has some useful functions that address this!  Thanks again, guys!